# How to achieve adding new node w/o down time and performance degradation

Tags: search, elasticsearch

How to add a new node in running elasticsearch cluster without any downtime during the data distribution and also no performance issues ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add new node, you will not have downtime during data relocation.
Some performance downgrade can happen.

You can change hwo much shards are relocation at once using setting: 
cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance

Docs here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html